# Weird result testing setInterval setImmediate operations per second

Tags: node.js, performance, setinterval, event-loop, setimmediate

I'm running on node `8.11` this test script:

```
let end = false;

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => { i++; }).unref();


let k = 0;
async function loop() {
  k++
  if (end === false)
    setImmediate(loop);
}

console.time('test');
loop()
  .then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      end = true;
      console.log('interval', i);
      console.log('recursion', k);
      console.timeEnd('test');
    }, 1000);
  })
```

And the output is:

```
interval 997
recursion 824687
test: 1001.831ms
```

But, if I comment these two lines:

```
  // if (end === false)
  //  setImmediate(loop);
```

The results are:

```
interval 537
recursion 1
test: 1003.882ms
```

I studied hard the [phases of nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) but I don't understand why a `setImmediate` should impact on the results of the interval function.

Do you have some explanations?

Comment: I am not an expert of Node.js event loop, however [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#check) it is stated that " If the poll phase becomes idle and scripts have been queued with `setImmediate()`, the event loop may continue to the check phase rather than waiting". So maybe that milliseconds difference is due to the check phase activity added by the `setImmediate()` invocation.

Comment: But I'm looking that the interval result are: 997 `i++` vs 537 `i++` without `setImmediate`, the timing is ok 1 sec

Comment: The recursion values are right (because in the second test I don't do that) but this shouldn't impact on setInterval (i think..)

Comment: interesting find...it replicates in the browser as well, with even smaller numbers for the interval

Comment: Tried also node 10 and 11 and same behaviour, I'm still investigating using inspector

Comment: A bit off-topic, but moving `console.timeEnd` before `console.log` gives more stable results, because console output requires some time, and that time may vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the timers on nodejs are not precise in the sense that they are just events in the event loop and so they can't know exactly when they will be triggered, that's why setTimeout says that it will execute at least after the time you provided.

> The timeout interval that is set cannot be relied upon to execute
> after that exact number of milliseconds. This is because other
> executing code that blocks or holds onto the event loop will push the
> execution of the timeout back. The only guarantee is that the timeout
> will not execute sooner than the declared timeout interval.

When you set the setImmediate, you are filling the event loop with a lot of immediate events and so you are pushing the timeout ones back on the queue.

Have in mind that event loop cycles haven't the same (an exact) duration in time, so even if you think setImmediate shouldn't affect timers, you are extending the event cycles duration in time.

Interesting articles:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c

Edit: as you pointed, in your case it is the opposite, there are more iterations when using setImmediate. In that case it may be related to the speed of the event loop being dynamic depending on the load of the program.

Comment: I don't read the articles yet, but with `setImmediate` and "pushing the timeout ones back on the queue" shouldn't be slower instead of faster? Or I have misunderstand?

Comment: if you read these articles, you will find that the event loop speed is dynamic, and it depends on the events queued and other factors, so probably it is related with that when using setInmediate, nodejs is running the event loop at max speed.

Comment: Javascript as a dynamic language processed by V8 engine, has tons of optimizations going underneath. So if it's common that benchmarks don't give precise data if you are not running them agains the final program, this kinds of experiments may have unexpected results due to things like optimization and loop speed.

Answer (score 0):

I've added logging to the original code

```js
let runSetImmediate = false; // setInterval 841 setImmediate 0
// let runSetImmediate = true; // setInterval 998 setImmediate 52751

const start = Date.now();
const log = [];

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    i++;
    log.push('i ' + i + '   ' + (Date.now() - start));
}).unref();

let k = 0;
async function loop() {
    if (runSetImmediate) {
        k++;
        log.push('- ' + k + '   ' + (Date.now() - start));
        setImmediate(loop);
    }
}

console.time("test");
loop().then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        runSetImmediate = false;
        console.timeEnd("test");
        console.log("setInterval", i, "setImmediate", k);
        for (const line of log) {
            console.log(line);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Now it's easy to see that `setInterval` alone (i.e. when `runSetImmediate = false`) executes not sooner than the interval, 1ms by default in current versions of Node.js. As https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#timers states,

> A timer specifies the threshold *after which* a provided callback *may be executed* rather than the exact time a person wants it to be executed. Timers callbacks will run as early as they can be scheduled after the specified amount of time has passed.

Actual average interval is 1.1-1.2ms on my machine and for my version of Node. Therefore we can get about 840 (and even 537 as in the question) executions per second.

On the other hand, `runSetImmediate = true` fills the event loop with callbacks for `setImmediate`, which execute on their own event loop phase without any minimal delay https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#check. In other words, `setImmediate` forces event loop to loop as fast as possible, thousands times per second.

This way the `timers` phase of the event loop is visited way more frequently, and actual interval is closer to 1ms. It's still a bit more than 1ms - measurements with duration of 10 seconds (and with removed logging) show its value as 1.002-1.006ms on my machine.